# How to run stored procedure with datetime input parameter on the line?

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I try to execute a SP with two date-time input parameters

```
[MySchema].[My_SP_Name] '2013-08-01' '2013-09-30'
```

But it kept on saying error syntax

Comment: Including what database you are using would be helpful (SqlServer, MySql, Sybase, DB2, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, I indeed miss the comma between parameters. I"m using SQL Server.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then you should upvote it and select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma between the parameters

```
[MySchema].[My_SP_Name] '2013-08-01', '2013-09-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a comma is missing between the 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on sybase iq and teradata and following are the calls :

```
Sybase : exec schema_name.sp_name 'date_1' , 'date_2'
TERADATA : call schema_name.sp_name ('date_1' , 'date_2')
```

The above assumes that dates are entered as varchar. if not, just remove the quotes and call.